# @Html.TextBoxFor with default help text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

How can I get a Default help text ("Type your name here" ) in
@Html.TextBoxFor/@Html.Editorfor

When a user clicks the box for typing , then the text will disappear.

Comment: Please read [ask] and try searching before asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to add placeholder html attribute in text box.

E.g.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @placeholder = "Type your name"})
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type="text" id="myID" placeholder="Insert name here" />
```

Placeholder attribute is what you want.